# Save <Select >Tag values into text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to ask if it is possible to save/export the values/data in a html Select Tag using javascript or jquery into text file?

This is my select tag.

```
<select id="mySelect" style="width: 581px; height:300px;" rows="10" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Then Im trying to use this javascript code, got it from the internet but it did'nt work. It creates a text file but it didnt get the values/data of the select tag.

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "directive.txt";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if ($('#sel1').val() == '')
        {
            alert('Please select ACCOUNT NAME, SCHEDULE and TASK first.');
        }
        else
        {
          window.webkitURL != null;
          downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        }
    downloadLink.click();
}

var button = document.getElementById('save');
button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);
button.addEventListener('click', doClear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select elements have `<option>` children. [MDN's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select):

> ```
> <!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
> <select name="text"> <!--Supplement an id here instead of using 'text'-->
>   <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
>   <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
>   <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
> </select>
> ```

So, you would `var myOptions = document.GetElementByName("text")` then iterate over `myOptions` `.push`ing each value (or whatever you want) into an array. Then write that array to your textfile.

Comment: What if there's no <option> tag, only the values/data of the <select> tag will be exported into text file? is it possible sir?

Comment: You would check for existence of option prior to acting on any data. If your select doesn't have any options, it's not native HTML. If it's a UI library like MDC-Web, the value will be in some other type of element. in any case you iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

I saw there was no  tag in your html. I think there must be  tag in the  and  tag. I improved your code as follows:

```
<body>

<label for="mySelect">Form input without an associated label </label>
<select id="mySelect" style="width: 581px; height:300px;" rows="10" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="id1" value="value1">id1</option>
    <option id="id2" value="value2">id2</option>
    <option id="id3" value="value3">id3</option>
    <option id="id4" value="value4">id4</option>
    <option id="id5" value="value5">id5</option>
</select>
<button id="save">save</button>
<script>
    function saveTextAsFile() {
        var textToWrite = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type: 'text/plain'});
        var fileNameToSaveAs = "directive.txt";

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        console.log("innerHTML -> " + downloadLink.innerHTML);
//        if ($('#sel1').val() == '') {
//            alert('Please select ACCOUNT NAME, SCHEDULE and TASK first.');
//        }
//        else {
            window.webkitURL != null;
            downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
//        }
        downloadLink.click();
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('save');
    button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have below HTML select element,

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I tested and below code is working. Basically as suggested by Ron above, you need to iterate over the options and add them to a string to print it on the text file.

```
function saveTextAsFile() {
    var textToWrite = "";
    $('#mySelect>option').each(function () {
        textToWrite += this.value + " ";
    });
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
        type: 'text/plain'
    });
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "directive.txt";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if ($('#sel1').val() == '') {
        alert('Please select ACCOUNT NAME, SCHEDULE and TASK first.');
    } else {
        window.webkitURL != null;
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    downloadLink.click();
}

var button = document.getElementById('save');
button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);
```