# Save options from a select to file with JS

Tags: javascript, select

Hello I have a select and an input button to browse files, and i would love to save the options in the select to a text file in the format:

line1
line2
line3
...

I have read this tutorial:

[Save <Select >Tag values into text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312308/save-select-tag-values-into-text-file)

But it does not seem to work. When i save, the options are written in the same line and only the first word for the option value is writte to the file.
I.E. my options are:

buy food
call john
print documents

the output in the file is:
buy call print

The code i use is:

```
       var textToWrite = "";
    $('#todolist>option').each(function () {
        textToWrite += this.value + "\n";
    });
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type: 'text/plain'});
        var fileNameToSaveAs = "directive.txt";

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        console.log("innerHTML -> " + downloadLink.innerHTML);

            window.webkitURL != null;
            downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);

        downloadLink.click();
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('file-save');
    button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);
```

I am using google's link for jquery:

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want also the text, not only the values?

```
$('#todolist>option').each(function () {
    textToWrite += this.value + "\n" + this.innerText + "\n";
});
```

Comment: Hi, thak you for answering, I want to write the option text in the file, one per line...
for example 

```
<option>do something</option>
<option do something else </option>
```
should generate:

do something
do something else

in the text file.

I have tried your portion of code (without the values, i don't need them)  and i get:

do somethingdo something else

all attached in a single line

Comment: Edited (changed one char).

Comment: Thank you very much tour the code was useful, i only had to put \r\n instead of just \n
now the problem is that iget an empty line at the end of the file, and when i reload back the list from the file i get an empty option, but it's not so important.